# Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(i2^{1/3}, 3^{1/4})$. Is this a Galois extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(i2^{1/3}, 3^{1/4})$. Is this a Galois extension?

Text: Essentials of Modern Algebra, Cheryl Chute Miller

Comment: That doesn't seem like a reason why it would not be a Galois extension as abelian Galois extensions are cyclotomic by the Kronecker-Weber theorem.

Comment: If you know all the roots of the splitting field are in $K$, then it is by definition a normal extension of $\mathbb Q$, and so, since separability isn't a problem over $\mathbb Q$, is Galois. No?

Comment: What are you getting for the minimal polynomials? The minimal polynomial of $i2^{1/3}$ should have degree 6, while the minimal polynomial of $3^{1/4}$ is of degree 4. In particular, their product is not of degree 7.

Comment: @lhf What about using $\alpha^3 = -2i$ to show $i \in K$?  Then you get $\omega \in K$

Comment: @JohnM what would the monic polynomial for this be if it was a root field?  I think it has degree 12 but K has degree 24 as an extension.  How can this be?

Comment: This follow up question regarding degree is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832318/continuation-on-let-k-mathbbqi21-3-31-4-is-this-a-galois-exten).

Answer (score 4):

The conjugates of $\alpha=i2^{1/3}$ are $2^{1/3}\omega^k$, for $k=1,3,5,7,9,11$ and $\omega$ is a primitive $12$-root of unit: $\omega = (\sqrt 3 + i)/2$.

$\alpha^3 = -2i$ and so $i \in K$ and $2^{1/3} \in K$.

The conjugates of $\beta=3^{1/4}$ are $3^{1/4}i^k$ for $k=0,1,2,3$, and so are all in $K$.

$\beta^2=\sqrt 3$ implies that $\omega \in K$ and so all conjugates of $\alpha$ are in $K$.

Hence, $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta)$ contains all conjugates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and so $K$ is normal.

Comment: How do we know $\omega \in K$?

Comment: @JohnM, now we do, thanks!

Comment: @lhf Okay but the degree of K is 24, but the degree of the minimum polynomial is 12?  Is that allowed?